# C# Salesforce MetaData API insert PickList Values

Tags: c#, api, salesforce

I am trying to write a C# program to insert picklist values into Salesforce using the MetaData API. I have been researching this and all of the examples that I have found are old and apparently most do not work anymore due to depreciation. More specifically Picklist.

I used the below example however Picklist is no longer in the MetadataService. Does anyone have any recent examples or know what this should be to insert picklist values.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_picklist.htm

```
            Picklist expenseStatus = new Picklist();
            PicklistValue unsubmitted = new PicklistValue();
            unsubmitted.fullName = "Unsubmitted";
            PicklistValue submitted = new PicklistValue();
            submitted.fullName = "Submitted";
            PicklistValue approved = new PicklistValue();
            approved.fullName = "Approved";
            PicklistValue rejected = new PicklistValue();
            rejected.fullName = "Rejected";
            expenseStatus.setPicklistValues(new PicklistValue[] {unsubmitted, submitted, approved, rejected} );

            CustomField expenseStatusField = new CustomField();
            expenseStatusField.fullName = "ExpenseReport__c.ExpenseStatus__c";
          
            expenseStatusField.label = "Expense Report Status";
            expenseStatusField.setType(FieldType.Picklist);
            expenseStatusField.setPicklist(expenseStatus);
            MetadataService.SaveResult[] update = ms.updateMetadata(new Metadata[] {expenseStatusField});
```

Comment: The link says to use PickList and has a link the the definition of a picklist.

Comment: ya but picklist is apparently depreciated

Comment: As stated in the link, "In API version 38.0 and later, Picklist is replaced by ValueSet on the CustomField type." That's what you'd need to be working with.